# VBA change name of connection

Tags: excel, vba

I need to modify the name of a connection in an excel sheet in VBA. I did so with:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Connections(name_of_conn).Name = name_of_conn2
```

where both names are string variables. Sometimes it works, sometimes it says invalid procedure or argument.

Comment: What is the value of `name_of_conn2` when it fails?

Comment: It is a string variable and is defined as the connection name of another pivot table which I delete, together with its connection itself, before attempting to change the name of the connection

Comment: Press CTRL+G to get debug window
Type in "Debug.print name_of_conn2" to see what it is trying to change to. Likely it will also not debug.print because name_of_conn2 isnt a valid string.

Comment: It debug. Print in the immediate window both values correctly...

Comment: Make sure you really need `ActiveWorkbook` (the workbook that is on top, this can change by a simple user click) or if you actually meant to use `ThisWorkbook` (the workbook this VBA code is in, and which will never change). You might be working with the wrong workbook. Also check `Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Connections.Count` in the case of error to check if there are connections at all.